# QSqlError Encoding

Tags: c++, qt

I have the error window for wrong connection attempt, and it's work fine if I haven't been connected before. But if I try new connection after succesfull one, the error message's encoding is messed up:

�����: ���� ������ "test125" �� ����������

instead of:

ВАЖНО: база данных "test125" не существует

```
if (!db.open()){
        QErrorMessage * error = new QErrorMessage();
        error->showMessage(db.lastError().databaseText());
        return;
    }
```

I'm using PostgreSQL wtih server encoding UTF-8 and client encoding Windows-1251.

I've tried to solve the problem by using QTextCodec, but it's didn't worked out (look's like because db.lastError().databaseText() is already a QString)
So how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us your DB settings?

Comment: You mean encoding, LC_COLLATE and CTYPE?
I dont know how to correctly insert it but there it is, encoding - UTF-8, LC_COLLATE - Russian_Russia.1251, LC_CTYPE - Russian_Russia.1251
                                          Список баз данных
    Имя    | Владелец | Кодировка |     LC_COLLATE      |      LC_CTYPE       |     Права доступа
-----------+----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------Test1251  | postgres | UTF8      | Russian_Russia.1251 | Russian_Russia.1251 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.